# Adding function to button Using Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

I am new to using QT designer and PYQT5 and I am having issues with adding a function to the add to cart button I have made on the GUI. The button is suppose to take the style from the dropdown box , the name , the color and the size of the item and display it in the console log below.

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(927, 701)
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 341, 391))
    self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 46, 41))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 46, 41))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 46, 41))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 46, 41))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 31, 21))
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 46, 41))
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 46, 41))
    self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
    self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 340, 46, 41))
    self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 110, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
    self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 150, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
    self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 190, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
    self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 230, 51, 20))
    self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
    self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 270, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 310, 51, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 350, 69, 22))
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
    self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 420, 341, 211))
    self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
    self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 46, 13))
    self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
    self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 46, 13))
    self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
    self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 46, 13))
    self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
    self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 41, 21))
    self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
    self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
    self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 81, 22))
    self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
    self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
    self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
    self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 131, 20))
    self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
    self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
    self.comboBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 41, 22))
    self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
    self.comboBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 110, 61, 22))
    self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
    self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
    self.lineEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 150, 51, 21))
    self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
    self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 20, 391, 261))
    self.groupBox_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
    self.comboBox_6 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_3)
    self.comboBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 121, 22))
    self.comboBox_6.setObjectName("comboBox_6")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
    self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
    self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 46, 41))
    self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
    self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
    self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 46, 41))
    self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
    self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
    self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 46, 41))
    self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
    self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
    self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 51, 41))
    self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
    self.comboBox_7 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_3)
    self.comboBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 160, 81, 22))
    self.comboBox_7.setObjectName("comboBox_7")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
    self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_3)
    self.lineEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 121, 20))
    self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
    self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_3)
    self.lineEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 110, 121, 20))
    self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
    self.Addtocart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_3)
    self.Addtocart.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 210, 141, 23))
    self.Addtocart.setObjectName("Addtocart")
    self.groupBox_4 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 300, 401, 241))
    self.groupBox_4.setObjectName("groupBox_4")
    self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.groupBox_4)
    self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 381, 211))
    self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 572, 111, 41))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 570, 111, 41))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 927, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuMenu.setObjectName("menuMenu")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.actionInstructions = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionInstructions.setObjectName("actionInstructions")
    self.menuMenu.addSeparator()
    self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionInstructions)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Billing Shipping"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Address"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Email"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tel"))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zip"))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "State"))
    self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "City"))
    self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Country"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "AL"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "AK"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "AS"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "AZ"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "AR"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "CA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "CO"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "CT"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "DE"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "DC"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "FM"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "FL"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("MainWindow", "GA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(13, _translate("MainWindow", "GU"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(14, _translate("MainWindow", "HI"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(15, _translate("MainWindow", "ID"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(16, _translate("MainWindow", "IL"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(17, _translate("MainWindow", "IN"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(18, _translate("MainWindow", "IA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(19, _translate("MainWindow", "KS"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(20, _translate("MainWindow", "KY"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(21, _translate("MainWindow", "LA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(22, _translate("MainWindow", "ME"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(23, _translate("MainWindow", "MH"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(24, _translate("MainWindow", "MD"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(25, _translate("MainWindow", "MA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(26, _translate("MainWindow", "MI"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(27, _translate("MainWindow", "MN"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(28, _translate("MainWindow", "MS"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(29, _translate("MainWindow", "MO"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(30, _translate("MainWindow", "MT"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(31, _translate("MainWindow", "NE"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(32, _translate("MainWindow", "NV"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(33, _translate("MainWindow", "NH"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(34, _translate("MainWindow", "NJ"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(35, _translate("MainWindow", "NM"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(36, _translate("MainWindow", "NY"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(37, _translate("MainWindow", "NC"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(38, _translate("MainWindow", "ND"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(39, _translate("MainWindow", "MP"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(40, _translate("MainWindow", "OH"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(41, _translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(42, _translate("MainWindow", "OR"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(43, _translate("MainWindow", "PW"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(44, _translate("MainWindow", "PA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(45, _translate("MainWindow", "PR"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(46, _translate("MainWindow", "RI"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(47, _translate("MainWindow", "SC"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(48, _translate("MainWindow", "SD"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(49, _translate("MainWindow", "TN"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(50, _translate("MainWindow", "TX"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(51, _translate("MainWindow", "UT"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(52, _translate("MainWindow", "VT"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(53, _translate("MainWindow", "VI"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(54, _translate("MainWindow", "VA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(55, _translate("MainWindow", "WA"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(56, _translate("MainWindow", "WV"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(57, _translate("MainWindow", "WI"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(58, _translate("MainWindow", "WY"))
    self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "USA"))
    self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Payment Info"))
    self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type"))
    self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number"))
    self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exp Date"))
    self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CCV"))
    self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Visa"))
    self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "American Express"))
    self.comboBox_3.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Master Card"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "01"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "02"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "03"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "04"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "05"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "06"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "07"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "08"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "09"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "10"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "11"))
    self.comboBox_4.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "12"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "2017"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2018"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2019"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "2020"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "2021"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "2022"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "2023"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "2024"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "2025"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "2026"))
    self.comboBox_5.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "2027"))
    self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Item Finder"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Jackets"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Shirts"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Tops/Sweaters"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Sweatshirts"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Pants"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Shorts"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Hats"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "accessories"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "Shoes"))
    self.comboBox_6.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "Skate"))
    self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Style"))
    self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
    self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Size"))
    self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Color"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Small"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Medium"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Large"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "30"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "31"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "32"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "33"))
    self.comboBox_7.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "34"))
    self.Addtocart.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add to Cart"))
    self.groupBox_4.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Status"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "STOP"))
    self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
    self.actionInstructions.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Credit"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())




def Billing ():
Name = self.lineEdit.setText()                      
Address = self.lineEdit_2.setText()
Email = self.lineEdit_4.setText()
Tel = self.lineEdit_5.setText()
Zip_code = self.lineEdit_6.setText()
City = self.lineEdit_7.setText()
State = self.comboBox.setText()
Country = self.comboBox_2.setText()



def Payment ():
Card_type = self.comboBox_3.setText()              
Card_number = self.lineEdit_8.setText()
Card_date = self.comboBox_4.setText()
Card_month = self.comboBox_5.setText()
Card_verif = self.lineEdit_9.setText()

def Item ():   
Item_Style = self.comboBox_6.setText()
Item_Name = self.lineEdit_10.setText()              
Item_Color = self.lineEdit_11.setText()
Item_Size = self.comboBox_7.set.setText()


self.Addtocart.clicked.connect(self.Add)

def Add (self):
entered_text = "Hello World"
`self.plainTextEdit.setText(entered_text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question. e.g. "The button" means which button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class that generates Qt Designer is oriented to the design, it is recommended to create a class that implements the logic.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Addtocart.clicked.connect(self.addCart)

    def addCart(self):
        style = self.comboBox_6.currentText()
        name = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        color = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        size = self.comboBox_7.currentText()
        text = "style: {style}, name: {name}, color: {color}, size: {size}".format(style=style, name=name, color=color, size=size)
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! , I will try this but , I wanted to print the output in Plaintextedit box below. Kind of like a console log @Eyllanesc

Comment: That didn't work , still isn't showing anything is the textbox below @eyllanesc

Comment: IT WORKS! , What is different ? @eyllanesc

Comment: Was it the f  in front of style ?